# O LogCat do Eclipse para Android exibe mensagens de Log?

Tags: android, log

```
public void ImprimeLog(){
        Log.i("Funcionando","");
        Log.e("Funcionando","");
        Log.v("Funcionando","");
        Log.w("Funcionando","");
        Log.d("Funcionando","");
    }
```

No Android Studio funciona, mas no Eclipse não está funcionando, isso é normal?

Comment: Não está confundindo o Console do Eclipse com o Tomcat log?

Comment: não, nem tenho o Tomcat instalado, estou falando do logcat do Android mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode encontrar no `Eclipse` em:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other… -> Android -> LogCat
```

Verifique se não está com nenhum **FILTRO** de log no Eclipse.

**Alternativa**

Se o `LogCat` está vazio, o `emulador` não está com foco na janela. Vá para o `DDMS` e tente clicar em `emulator` na lista de dispositivos (`Devices`) no topo esquerdo da tela.

O mesmo acontece com seu celular. Você só precisa clicar no nome do seu celular pra que as mensagens do LogCat venham.

**Update**

Devido à intermitência (hora sim, hora não) de o Eclipse exibir corretamente o LogCat relatada pelo **@daniel12345smith** e também ao relato do **@WellingtonAvelino**, o problema pode ser considerado um `BUG` no ATD ou no Eclipse, tornando a resposta sem objetivo.

Comment: Valeu, mas eu já fiz tudo isso e mesmo assim nada. As vezes aparece, às vezes não, no Android Studio aparecia todos os logs e erros normalmente.

Comment: Se há intermitência entre aparecer e não aparecer, o Eclipse pode estar bugado mesmo.

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho, passo por isso direto acredito que seja um bug do ADT

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino, ah, então é isso!

Answer (score 1):

Para contornar essa "intermitência" utilize da seguinte maneira para printar seus `logs` via `LogCat`:

```
System.out.println("Printa logCat - teste 1""+vendedor);

System.out.println("Printa logCat - teste 2");

System.out.println("Printa logCat - teste 3"+usuarios.toString());
```

**Saída :**

> 07-01 09:57:37.429: I/System.out(22125): Printa logCat - teste 1
>   Vendedor [identificador=null, nome=16235676883, senha=0]
>
> 07-01> 09:57:37.429: I/System.out(22125): Printa logCat - teste 2
>
> 07-01> 09:57:37.429: I/System.out(22125): Printa logCat - teste 3
>   Vendedor> [identificador=null, nome=16235676883, senha=0,
>   atualizacao=Mon Jun 29> 00:00:00 BRT 2015]

O interessante de se usar o `sysout` como saida é que você pode printar tanto `Objetos` como `String` e pode também utilizar `toString();`